# gridjs width own Table and Jquery

Tags: gridjs

i want to use gridjs width my own Table.

What i have is:

```
        <script>

        $("table#myTable").Grid
        (

            ({
                pagination: true,
                from: $("table#myTable").current
            })
        );

    </script>
```

But the script say me

Uncaught TypeError: container is undefined

Can you Help me Please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Grid.js table from an existing HTML table, simply reference your table in the jQuery selector and leave the `from` config empty, e.g.

```
$("table#myTable").Grid({ pagination: true });
```

The jQuery wrapper understands that your element is an existing table and uses the `from` config automatically, see https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs-jquery